# Shortening this IF statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, refactoring

I don't like wide code, especially when it forces me to scroll.  So having written this:

```
If _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text = "N/A" Or _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text = String.Empty Then
            dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

Is there a decent way to thin it down, make it more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract `_item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text` into a local variable, e.g.

```
String text = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text

If text = "N/A" Or text = String.Empty Then
            dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

Alternatively, you may want to extract the whole check into a separate method:

```
If isNotFilled(_item.SubItems(pd.perioddate)) Then
            dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

This would make the code more readable and allow you to reuse the checking logic.

Comment: I would rename text variable to mean something, dim periodDate = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text

Comment: We should also consider Select Case rather than introducing a local variable? `Select Case _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text Case "N/A", "" dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False End Select`

Comment: @Iain, agreed, I just could not find a good name - was considering `findSomeMeaningfulNameForThis` for a minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
string obj = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text;

If obj = "N/A" Or obj = String.Empty Then
            dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

**ALSO**

enable Word Warp in visual studio to stop having to scroll.

go to

Tools->Options->Text Editor->All languages->Word Warp

dont forget to enable 'Show all settings'

Comment: The OP's question is in Visual Basic - the first line of your answer is in C#.

Comment: @Jazza: I think VB users are able to (and used to) ignore a `;`

Comment: @Jazza, @Henk Yes, and we can also mentally change `string obj` into `Dim obj As String`  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
With _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate)
    If .Text = "N/A" Or .Text = String.Empty Then
        dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
    End If
End With
```

Cue argument regarding the merits/evils of WITH :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple fields that can contain N/A, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
Dim invalidValues As String() = {"N/A", String.Empty}

If invalidValues.Contains(_item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text) Then
    dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

Or, if it's just about scrolling, you can use the VB line continuation character `_`:

```
If _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text = "N/A" _
Or _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text = String.Empty Then
    dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

BTW: Here, I'd suggest [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) instead of `Or`.

Answer (score 1):

We should at least mention [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

```
Select Case _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text     
  Case "N/A", "" 
    dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False 
End Select
```

Also consider extracting a helper function

```
Function IsNotApplicable(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
  Return (s = "N/A") Or (s = "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim date as String = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text

If date = "N/A" Or date = String.Empty Then 
            dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, you can use a local variable. You could also shorten the line additionally, by using the [line continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641(v=VS.71).aspx) character `_`.

```
String period = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate);

If period = "N/A" Or _
   period = String.Empty Then
        dtpDeadlineforAP.Checked = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suppgest an Helper Class or ExtensionMethod:

```
If StringIsNullOrEmptyOrNA(stringval) Then
     ...
End If


If stringval.IsNullOrEmptyOrNa() Then
     ....
End If


Public Function StringIsNullOrEmptyOrNA(ByVal input as String) as Boolean
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) OrElse input.Equals("N/A")
End Function


<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> 
Public Function IsNullOrEmptyOrNa(ByVal input As String)
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) OrElse input.Equals("N/A")
End Sub
```

Comment: bear in mind that extension methods were introduced with VB.Net version 9.0 (VS 2008). The OP does not mention which version of VB.Net/VS he is using.

Comment: That's why I added examples for both ways in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it down to 3 lines and 63 columns. I have replaced the traditional [If construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs(v=VS.90).aspx) with the newer [If operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=VS.90).aspx). The code will also handle the case of `Text` being a null reference and will short-circuit using the `OrElse` operator. If you are willing to declare a couple of extension methods you could whittle this down to one short line, but that conflicts with the spirit of my answer.

```
Dim tx = _item.SubItems(pd.perioddate).Text
Dim dtp = dtpDeadlineforAP
dtp.Checked = If(tx = "N/A" OrElse tx = "", False, dtp.Checked)
```

Comment: I think we can still improve. VB.Net treats a null reference string as equal to "", so the whole first line could be dropped.

Comment: @MarkJ: I was not aware of that...until now. Thanks for pointing that out!